# Python while loop - without condition?

Tags: python

I understand this code:

```
c = 5

while c != 0:
    print(c)
    c -= 1
```

**Output will be**:

```
5
4
3
2
1
```

But eventually the code below:

```
c = 5

while c:
    print(c)
    c -= 1
```

**Gave me the same result.**

I've read something about conversion into bool automatically? Does compiler knows if c > 0 then it would be true for the while loop, and if c = 0 then it would be false?

Comment: Yes - it's the same as `if c` - whereby - it's truthfulness is tested...

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing